# how to make a function into Promise

Tags: function, promise, fs

Hi I am trying to make  function addUserToDBs to a promise but I wonder why my code is not working? 
Could anyone please advice? thank you

the original function :

```
const addUserToDBs = (username) => {

    username = username.trim().toLowerCase();
    const existingUser = userDatas.users.find(user =>user.name === username);
    if (existingUser) {
        return { error: 'Username is taken' };
    }
    let newuser = {
        name: username,
        id: uuid.v4(),
        rooms: [],
        joinDate: +new Date()
    };
    userDatas.users.push(newuser);
    save(userDatas, userDB_PATH);
    return userDatas.users;


 };
```

the save function used in the function above is also a promise

```
const fs = require("fs");
exports.save =(data, PATH) =>{
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.writeFile(PATH, JSON.stringify(data), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
    });
   });
  }
```

the following code is not working, I wonder why?

```
 const addUserToDBs = (username) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    username = username.trim().toLowerCase();
    const existingUser = userDatas.users.find(user =>user.name === username);
    if (existingUser) {
        reject({ error: 'Username is taken' }) ;
    }else{  

    let newuser = {
        name: username,
        id: uuid.v4(),
        rooms: [],
        joinDate: +new Date()
    };
        resolve(newuser)
    }

    userDatas.users.push(newuser);
    save(userDatas, userDB_PATH);
    return userDatas.users;

   })

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling resolve in the middle of your function so the save(userDatas) function is never reached. Also fs.writeFile() is an asynchronous function that you are not waiting to complete before returning the userDatas.users. Consider converting to async/await...

```
const addUserToDBs = async username => {
    username = username.trim().toLowerCase();
    const existingUser = userDatas.users.find(user => user.name === username);
    if (existingUser) {
        throw new Error({ error: 'Username is taken' }) ;
    } 
    const newUser = ({
        name: username,
        id: uuid.v4(),
        rooms: [],
        joinDate: new Date()
    })
    userDatas.users.push(newUser);
    await save(userDatas, userDB_PATH)
    return newUser
}


addUserToDBs(userName)
    .then(newUser => {
       //do whatever you want with the new user
    })
```